# awk - Find duplicate records in multiple files

Tags: file, awk, compare, text-processing

I want to find duplicated records in third column of one file (f1) with multiple files (f2,f3,....fn) and print result against every row (in new column) with format: Filename/FirstColumn

```
f1
1. 11:10 *Jane> login
2. 11:15 *Bob>  login
   11:16 *Bob>  logout
3. 11:45 *Jane> login
4. 01:20 *John>  login
5. 02:30 *Deborah  logout

f2
1. 12:10 *Jane> login
2. 13:00 *Dorothy  logout
3. 13:15 *Bob>  login
   14:16 *Bob>  logout
4. 15:45 *Jane> login
5. 06:20 *John>  login

f3
1. 15:10 *Jane> login
2. 15:50 *Mark> login
3. 16:10 *Dorothy  logout
4. 17:18 *Bob>  login
   18:16 *Bob>  logout
5. 19:45 *Jane> login
6. 20:21 *John>  login
```

output to f1-dup

```
f1-dup
1. 11:10 *Jane> login    f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
2. 11:15 *Bob>  login    f1/2_f2/3_f3/4
   11:16 *Bob>  logout
3. 11:45 *Jane> login    f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
4. 01:20 *John>  login   f1/4_f2/5_f3/6
5. 02:30 *Deborah  logout
```

I tried several methods but none of them works for me.

Comment: What are the sometimes present, sometimes absent numbers at the start of the lines?  Are they part of the data file, or part of your presentation?  What's the significance of the number being absent?  Which is the third column?  This arises in part because of the erratic numbers — are you looking at the values of login and logout only? You also seem to be concerned about the names.  There also seems to be a systematic 1 hour and 4 hour gap between entries for 'Jane Login'.  Why do you want the 11:10 value for Jane's login, not 12:10, etc?  What is the `f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5` notation?

Comment: Is it file name slash comma-list-line-numbers underscore next file name etc?  Why do you have Jane Login twice in the output with the same details apart from the time portion?  Why only two time portions?  Sorry, in case you haven't gathered, I regard your question as unanswerable because you've not explained carefully enough the rhyme and reason behind the desired answer.  I also think you should be showing what you've tried — your best effort to date, along with what it produces and why that isn't correct and what you'd do about it if you could.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explanation. First column is autoncrement number. There's missing number when value in previous row is equal to the current row:  2. 11:15 *Bob>  11:16 *Bob> .  Third column is names. For example *Bob>  Values in second column - time are not important. f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5  resepresent where  *Bob> exists in other files. According first column: 1. 2. 3. 4. etc

Comment: Please add that information to the question.  That dramatically complicates the processing. Get "them" to stop being inconsistent with the output format. It makes life hell.  I wonder how much effort went into producing that layout?  And 'value' seems to mean the name-like column since neither the time nor the operation is necessarily the same.  Do you have any say in the format?

Comment: Operation - login-logout  (column 4) doesnt matter. I need comparison only with "the name" column.

Comment: "I tried several methods but none of them works for me." Oops, You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all.  Good luck ;-/

Comment: Please EDIT THE QUESTION!!!  Why do `*Dorothy` and `*Mark>` not appear in the output?  What are the criteria for including or excluding people?  Why does the output include the 'operation' information if it doesn't matter?  Which operation should be included in the output?  Why does the output include a time value?  Which time value should be included?  Why does the output sometimes include the serial number and sometimes not?  It is painful dealing with that.  Why do `*Bob>` and `*Jane>` appear several times in the output?  What's the benefit of that?

Comment: Note that the line numbers in the output aren't simply the line numbers from the input; they seem to be related to the identifier number that's sometimes part of a record.  But then why is the numberless `*Bob>` line in the output — with no other file/line entries listed?  It's the same name?  What would happen if there were several pairs of consecutive `*Bob>` lines in the file (with other names in between)?  What would happen if there were 4 consecutive `*Bob>` entries with no other names between? What would the input look like? What would be the expected output? What if those are in `f2`?

Comment: *Dorothy and *Mark> are not included because they doesn's exist in first file (f1). I'm trying to find where every Name in file1 exists in rest of the files. Additional column (output) show where exaclty Name is duplicated in f1, f2, f3.

Comment: Apparently @JonathanLeffler's suggestion to `Please add that information to the question` and later `Please EDIT THE QUESTION!!!` weren't clear. Pretty please? Assuming you want help - no-one wants to wade through a bunch of comments trying to piece together info and requirements so you stand a better chance of getting help if you put it all in one place and LISTEN to the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
 awk '{id=$1; k=$3 FS $4; pid=sub(/\./,"",id)} 
     NR==FNR{if(pid) a[k]=(a[k]?a[k]",":"\t"FILENAME"/")id
             keyfile=FILENAME; next}
     FILENAME==keyfile{$(NF+1)=a[k];print;next}
     k in a && pid{a[k]=a[k] (fx[k]!=FILENAME?"_"FILENAME"/":",") id;
                              fx[k]=FILENAME}' f1 f2 f3 f1

1. 11:10 *Jane> login   f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
2. 11:15 *Bob> login    f1/2_f2/3_f3/4
11:16 *Bob> logout
3. 11:45 *Jane> login   f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
4. 01:20 *John> login   f1/4_f2/5_f3/6
5. 02:30 *Deborah logout        f1/5
```

I think it can be simplified further, also the formatting of the unnumbered record can be fixed.

Comment: Devious with the use of file `f1` twice in the argument list so that there isn't a need for an END block.  That's nearly as inscrutable as the question, so it is a fitting answer.

Comment: Is there a way file/id to be not present when it's found on the same id

Comment: I didn't understand your question.  The script uses first file entries as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the last line of the expected output should include `f1/5`, then the following code does the job slightly less deviously than the other answer, but it does so more verbosely — but without processing any of the files twice.  The encoding is painful, though.  There's a logical line number which is the leading `1.` on a line with 4 fields (lines with 3 fields don't count as logical lines) as well as the physical line number in the file (`FNR`).

#### `script.awk`

```
FILENAME != ofn { ofn = FILENAME; log_line_num = 0 }
FNR == NR {
            line[FNR] = $0
            len = length($0)
            if (len > maxlen)
                maxlen = len
            if (NF == 4)
            {
                name = $3
                names[name]++
                name_on_line[FNR] = name
            }
            numlines++
          }
NF == 4   { name = $3
            log_line_num++
            if (name in names)
            {
                if (name_in_file[FILENAME,name]++ == 0)
                {
                    us = (data[name] != "") ? "_" : ""
                    extra = us FILENAME "/" log_line_num
                }
                else
                    extra = "," log_line_num
                data[name] = data[name] extra
            }
          }
END       {
            fmt = "%-" maxlen "s   %s\n"
            for (i = 1; i <= numlines; i++)
            {
                if (i in name_on_line)
                    printf(fmt, line[i], data[name_on_line[i]])
                else
                    print line[i]
            }
          }
```

Explanation:

- Keep a record of the current file name and reset the logical line number when the name changes.
- For the lines in the first file:

  - record the line in the line array indexed by physical line number (FNR — file record number).
  - track the longest input line
  - if the number of fields is 4, record that the name exists, and that it appears on the physical line number
- For the lines with 4 fields (in all files), it:

  - increment the logical line number
  - if the name is one of those in the first file, then check whether the name has already been seen in the current file (`names_in_file`)
  - if not, then add an underscore to `data[name]` if it is non-empty and add the file name, a slash and the logical line number to `data[name]`
  - else add a comma and the logical line number to `data[name]`
- At the end

  - create a convenient format strings to put the file information 3 spaces after the longest line in file 1
  - for each physical line number in file 1
  - if the line has 4 fields (`name_on_line[i]` is defined), then print the saved line plus the line numbers for the name on the line from the `data` array
  - else just print the saved (3 field) line

#### Example output

```
1. 11:10 *Jane> login       f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
2. 11:15 *Bob>  login       f1/2_f2/3_f3/4
   11:16 *Bob>  logout
3. 11:45 *Jane> login       f1/1,3_f2/1,4_f3/1,5
4. 01:20 *John>  login      f1/4_f2/5_f3/6
5. 02:30 *Deborah  logout   f1/5
```

#### Alternative data files

`file.1`:

```
1. c2 888888  somestuff
2. c2 999999  somestuff
   c2 999999  somestuff
3. c2 777777  somestuff
4. c2 666666  somestuff
5. c2 888888  somestuff
```

`file.2`:

```
1. c2 333333  somestuff
2. c2 999999  somestuff
3. c2 444444  somestuff
4. c2 777777  somestuff
5. c2 888888  somestuff
6. c2 555555  somestuff
```

`file.3`:

```
1. c2 333333  somestuff
2. c2 999999  somestuff
3. c2 444444  somestuff
4. c2 777777  somestuff
5. c2 666666  somestuff
6. c2 888888  somestuff
7. c3 222222  somestuff
```

Alternative sample output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.[123]
1. c2 888888  somestuff   file.1/1,5_file.2/5_file.3/6
2. c2 999999  somestuff   file.1/2_file.2/2_file.3/2
   c2 999999  somestuff
3. c2 777777  somestuff   file.1/3_file.2/4_file.3/4
4. c2 666666  somestuff   file.1/4_file.3/5
5. c2 888888  somestuff   file.1/1,5_file.2/5_file.3/6
$
```